# MVC 5 Objects in Models and DB Storage

Tags: database, object, asp.net-mvc-5, models, relationships

I'm new to MVC and I am trying to work out how to connect different models to display in a view Example

```
Model Teams
int TeamID
string Team_Name

Model Players
int PlayerID
string PlayerName
```

Now I want this information stored in a database so how would I go about linking the two?

So in the Players Model I can use either `Team Team or int TeamID`

`Team_ID` I can store in a db table but then have to somehow include the team table when I pull a list of players. or `TEAM Team` which I can then view the team name by modelItem.team.team_name but cant store a TEAM object in the database.

I know this is basic in terms of MVC but im just struggling to get my head round it.

Any suggestions or links to solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entity classes should look something like:

```
public  class Team
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Team")]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

With that, with an instance of `Player`, you can simply do:

```
 player.Team.Name
```

To get the name of the team. If you have a collection of players you're iterating through, you should eagerly load `Team` first, so you don't end up with N+1 queries:

```
var players = db.Players.Include(m => m.Team).ToList();
```

If you need to go the other way, then, you can load the list of players from an instance of `Team` as well:

```
var players = team.Players.ToList();
```

Likewise, you can eagerly load the players to minimize queries:

```
var team = db.Teams.Include(m => m.Players).SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == teamId);
```

For what it's worth, your class and property names defy conventions. Notice the class and property names in the sample code I provided. An entity class' name should always be singular: `Team`, not `Teams`. Property names should be pascal-cased and run together: LikeThis, not likeThis or Like_This. Also, it's an antipattern to include the class name in the property name. The `Name` property belongs to `Team`, for example, so of course it's the name of the team. There is zero point in prefixing it with `Team` (`TeamName`), and it only makes your code more verbose. For example, which reads better: `team.Name` or `team.TeamName`?